# If $\int_0^t X_sdB_s$ is a martingale, does $\mathbb E[\int_0^t X_s^2ds]<\infty $?

Tags: martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let $$M_t=\int_0^t X_sdB_s,$$ being a martingale. Does $$\mathbb E[\int_0^t X_s^2ds]<\infty \ \ ?$$

I'm asking this question because, I know that if $$\int_0^t X_s^2ds<\infty \ \ a.s.$$
then $(M_t)$ is a local martingale, i.e. there is a sequence $(tau_n)$ of stopping time s.t. $\tau_n\nearrow \infty $ a.s. s.t. $(M_{\tau_n\wedge t})_t$ is a martingale for all $n$. Now, does the $(M_{\tau_n\wedge t})_t$ satisfy $$\mathbb E\left[\int_0^{\tau_n\wedge t} X_s^2ds\right]<\infty ,$$
and thus, we can use itô isometry on $(M_{\tau_n\wedge t})$.

Comment: $\mathbb E[\int_0^tX_s^2\,ds]<+\infty$ iff $M_t$ is a **square-integrable** martingale.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a process that is not square-integrable but still gives rise to a martingale when integrated w.r.t. Brownian motion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982344/is-there-a-process-that-is-not-square-integrable-but-still-gives-rise-to-a-marti)